# How do I get JUST the groups a user is in from AD without nesting

Tags: c#, active-directory

I want to get a list of the groups a user is **directly** a member of (i.e. without nesting). Effectively, to retrieve what you see in the Member Of tab in AD:

[image]

I am using the following to get the list of groups:

```
public List<GroupPrincipal> GetGroups(string userName)
{
    List<GroupPrincipal> result = new List<GroupPrincipal>();
    PrincipalContext myDomain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "mydomain.com");
    UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(myDomain, userName);
    if (user != null)
    {
        PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> groups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();
        try
        {
            // iterate over all groups
            foreach (Principal p in groups)
            {
                // make sure to add only group principals
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {
                    result.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

However, this retrieves all groups including nested ones. (i.e. if there is a group in the list in the screenshot above which is nested in another group - both groups are returned).

How can I just retrieve the list as shown in Active Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAuthorizationGroups()` will get all security groups recursively + additional groups such as the primary group or dynamic principals evaluated on logon.

Use [`GetGroups()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357862(v=vs.110).aspx) instead:

> This method returns only the groups of which the principal is directly a member; no recursive searches are performed. Recursive search results are available for user principal objects. For more information, see the GetAuthorizationGroups method.